# Curl applied on a simple example that gets a HTTP page ->storing all in a MySQL-DB

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, curl

update: the answer from virtualeyes (below) looks pretty nice: but now a bit code-sanititzing should be applied:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.aktive-buergerschaft.de/buergerstiftungsfinder");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
$buffer = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result = explode(",", $buffer);
print_r($result);
```

and with the corrections we have something like the following:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.aktive-buergerschaft.de/buergerstiftungsfinder");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
$buffer = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result = explode(",", $buffer);
foreach($result as $k => $v) {echo $k." ".$v} 
if $v is itself an array) 
   // print_r($result);
```

see the additional infos from virtualeye... [a big thanks to Virtualeye]

```
yes, print_r just prints out the response, 
in this case presumably as an array (if viewing the output in web browser, 
do view-source to see structured array). 
Depending on num dimensions, we could do, 
foreach($result as $k => $v) {echo $k." ".$v} 
to view and work with data 
(adding sub foreach loops accordingly; i.e. 
if $v is itself an array)
```

here the **old text from the original question:**

today i want to apply Curl on a  very simple example that gets a HTTP page - review 
in order to harvest the data of this pretty simple

see this totally easy page: http://www.aktive-buergerschaft.de/buergerstiftungsfinder
here we have a list of Foundations: We can see a bunch (approx 1000 records on Foundations). Well - my intention is to store the data in a locally database (favourite db is MySQL):

here is my simple approach - what is missing are two parts: The processing of the results and the storing of the results of the parser - into the MySQL-DB. This part goes somewhat over my head.

Well the result of the Fetching with Curl should be given to arrays - shouldn ´t it!? If someone can help me here i would be glad!

```
<?php
//
// A very simple example that gets a HTTP page.
//

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.aktive-buergerschaft.de/buergerstiftungsfinder");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);


curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

// well here i want to put the results into an array... [multidimensioal or not !?! ]

?>
```

see the example here on this page: (at the top)

```
Bürgerstiftung Lebensraum Aachen
rechtsfähige Stiftung des bürgerlichen Rechts
Ansprechpartner: Hubert Schramm
Alexanderstr. 69/ 71
52062 Aachen
Telefon: 0241 - 4500130
Telefax: 0241 - 4500131
Email: info@buergerstiftung-aachen.de
www.buergerstiftung-aachen.de
>> Weitere Details zu dieser Stiftung
```

The **link "Weitere Details zu dieser Stiftung"** which is: in english
More details to this Foundation"

this link has to be followed and the results (also) to be  parsed. If you follow the link then you see: There are some additional infos that should be stored too!

Well - what is needed now: I need to have the details for the arrays Can any body enlarge the codebits that can be seen above - and give me a hint!? I look forward to this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.aktive-buergerschaft.de/buergerstiftungsfinder");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
$buffer = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result = explode(",", $buffer);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: hello dear virtualeyes - many many thanks for the hints - i will try it out later tonight and come back and report all my findings... Best regards !!

Comment: hello Virtualeyes - thx again.  The results are given back in a bit disordered way. Is there any chhance to get all a bit more ordered and sanitized... !? Look forward to any hint

Comment: yes, print_r just prints out the response, in this case presumably as an array (if viewing the output in web browser, do view-source to see structured array). Depending on num dimensions, you could do, foreach($result as $k => $v) {echo $k." ".$v} to view and work with data (adding sub foreach loops accordingly; i.e. if $v is itself an array)